# Cannot read account number from list

Tags: c#

I am trying to read AccountNumber from a text file, but it does not seem to be reading the AccountNumber from the text file, and I can confirm that the text file location string is correct. Also, note that currently the user is only set to access BasicAccountTestRepository class, but I am trying to get the LoadAccounts method to be able to call GetAccounts() from FileAccountRepository.cs. According to my instructions, I should be able to read from the text file in this class. I am getting a NullReferenceException on LoadAccounts method, says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

**Accounts.txt**

```
AccountNumber,Name,Balance,Type
10001,Free Account,100,F
20002,Basic Account,500,B
30003,Premium Account,1000,P
```

**FileAccountRepository.cs**

```
public class FileAccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    public Account _account = new Account();

    public void GetUsers() {
        string path = @".\Accounts.txt";
        string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(path);


        for (int i = 1; i < rows.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] columns = rows[i].Split(',');

            //Account account = new Account();
            _account.AccountNumber = columns[0];
            _account.Name = columns[1];
            _account.Balance = Decimal.Parse(columns[2]);
            if (columns[3] == "F")
            {
                _account.Type = AccountType.Free;
            }
            else if (columns[3] == "B")
            {
                _account.Type = AccountType.Basic;
            }
            else if (columns[3] == "P")
            {
                _account.Type = AccountType.Premium;
            }

            accounts.Add(_account);
        }
    }


    public Account LoadAccount(string AccountNumber)
    {            
        if (accounts.Any(x => x.AccountNumber == AccountNumber))
        {
            return _account;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void SaveAccount(Account account)
    {
        _account = account;
    }        
}
```

**AccountManager.cs**

```
...
public AccountLookupResponse LookupAccount(string accountNumber)
    {
        AccountLookupResponse response = new AccountLookupResponse();
        FileAccountRepository fileAccount = new FileAccountRepository(); //NullReferenceException

        fileAccount.GetUsers();
        response.Account = _accountRepository.LoadAccount(accountNumber);

        if(response.Account == null)
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = $"{accountNumber} is not a valid account.";
        }
        else
        {
            response.Success = true;
        }

        return response;
    }
...
```

Comment: You should start your index at 1 for the loop. The first row is just the headers

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I have a null reference exception, let me edit.

Comment: You fields `_account` make no sense. It's a `static` with instantiation with itself which is null to begin with. Also why do you call `GetAccounts()` if your not doing anything with it.

Comment: Not sure if I even need _account method here. GetAccounts() is not setting a list properly?

Comment: The _account static has values in BasicAccountTestRepository, but FileAccountRepository does not. My intention for FileAccountRepository is to just read from text file.

Comment: In _FileAccountRepository_  you have declared a static variable called __account_ of type Account. Now in its initialization you try to use properties of the same static variable. Of course because you are initializing the _account variable its properties are not able to read them because the _account is still null, so you get a NRE. Really weird way to shoot yourself.

Comment: I got rid of it as I am already setting an account in my for loop, now I have to figure out what I need to implement in LoadAccount() and SaveAccount().

Comment: Looks like I am going to have to call FileAccountRepository and not just GetAccounts() as a list.

Comment: @Steve I updated my code for FileAccountRepository, however looks like it cannot find the AccountNumber now. Null error is gone now.

Comment: Is GetUsers a Typo? It seems you are reading accounts there not users.

Comment: Sorry I changed it to GetUsers(), now is GetUsers()

Comment: Now your problem is caused by the global variable _account in the FileAccountRepository. You are always adding it to you list. Inside the loop you change the values of the same variable and thus you are ending with the last values. I bet that if you search for accountNumber 30003 you will find it. Create a new instance of Account inside the for loop and add that instance.

Comment: But then LoadAccount() will not access it, how could this be accessed then?

Comment: You might want to name your method properly. A method called `GetUsers` that doesn't return anything but all it does is loading the account and your `LoadAccount` is actually a return which should be `GetAccount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the code in your GetUsers. This code is wrong because is adding the same instance to your list. This will end with many entries in your list but for the same Account instance and all of these entries show the same data. The data assigned to the variable _account in the last loop.

You need to have a variable of type Account declared and initialized inside the loop. In this way every entry in the list is a different instance with different data

```
public class FileAccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

    public void GetUsers() {
        string path = @".\Accounts.txt";
        string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(path);


        for (int i = 1; i < rows.Length; i++)
        {
            Account data = new Account();
            string[] columns = rows[i].Split(',');

            data.AccountNumber = columns[0];
            data.Name = columns[1];
            data.Balance = Decimal.Parse(columns[2]);
            if (columns[3] == "F")
            {
                data.Type = AccountType.Free;
            }
            else if (columns[3] == "B")
            {
                data.Type = AccountType.Basic;
            }
            else if (columns[3] == "P")
            {
                data.Type = AccountType.Premium;
            }

            accounts.Add(data);
        }
    }
```

Now when you need to find an account by AccountNumber you call the method LoadAccount searching the Account from the list

```
public Account LoadAccount(string AccountNumber)
{            
    return accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountNumber == AccountNumber);
}
```

FirstOrDefault will search your list for a matching value according to your lambda expression and return the account found or null.

Comment: Ok, I tried what you did, but it still cannot read the account number, maybe I am doing something wrong. I will post github url here: https://github.com/alextech1/SWGBanks  . Meanwhile I will try to figure it out.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by the AccountManager.Create called in the AccountLookupWorkflow in its Execute. This method creates a _PremiumAccountTestRepository_ (according to the config value) This class has no knowledge of your class _FileAccountRepository_. The call to LoadAccount is made against the test data hard coded in the PremiumAccountTestRepository

Comment: Actually its not supposed to be an option for FileAccountRepository. So I am going to have to figure it out.